# Tic Tac Toe - Letter 'X' AI doesn't work (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, tic-tac-toe

i'm working on my tic tac toe AI for my assignment in my C# course. At the beginning of the game, the game will let the player choose a letter between letter 'X' and letter 'O'.

If the player chooses letter 'X' then automatically the letter 'O' will be the AI.
If the player chooses letter 'O' then automatically the letter 'X' will be the AI.

Problem: When I chooses letter 'O' the game makes me do the second turn (which is for letter 'X' and AI will do that move/turn, not me).

**Question: Is my logic on the code is really wrong? If yes, What changes on the logic of my code I need to change?**

P.S. I use Visual Studio 2015

Here is my code in the part that i know there's something wrong:

```
namespace Puh_Tak_Teh{
public partial class Form3 : Form{
    private bool first_turn; //X - true , Y - false
    public int turn_count = 0;

    Image X = Image.FromFile("C:\\Users\\Denzell\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\Puh Tak Teh\\x.png");
    Image O = Image.FromFile("C:\\Users\\Denzell\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\Puh Tak Teh\\o.png");

    public Form3(Form2 form2){

        InitializeComponent();
        if (form2.player_turn == true){
            first_turn = true; //from form 2, if the player chose 'X'
        } //then the form here bool first_turn will be set to true
        else if (form2.player_turn == false){
            first_turn = false; //from form 2, if the player chose O
        }//then the form here bool first_turn will be set to true false
    }
    private void Show(Object sender, EventArgs e){
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Button b = (Button)sender;
        if (first_turn) //if the first_turn is true (which is X)
        {
            b.Image = X;
            b.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        }
        else //if the first_turn is false (which is O)
        {
            b.Image = O;
            b.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        }

        first_turn = !first_turn; //

        b.Enabled = false; //disables the button if it is already clicked
        turn_count++; //counts 
        CheckWinner();

        if (!first_turn) //I think the logical error / my problem starts  from here
        {
            PuhTakTehMind();
        }

    }
    private void PuhTakTehMind() //private method in which the game would decide which what move the AI would make
    {
        Button AddMove = null; //makes/performs the move

        AddMove = look_for_win_or_block(X); //loof for win ( letter X)
        if (AddMove == null)
        {
            AddMove = look_for_win_or_block(O); //look for block (letter O)
            if (AddMove == null)
            {
                AddMove = look_for_corner();
                if (AddMove == null)
                {
                    AddMove = look_for_open_space();
                }
            }
        }
        if (turn_count != 9)
            AddMove.PerformClick();
    }
```

Entire Code: https://pastebin.com/wJZXJuPC

Comment: Far too much code. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [ask], and then come back and [edit] your post accordingly. Or, better yet, use the debugger to step through your code and either figure out what the problem is (in which case you won't need to ask at all) or narrow down the problem to a small area of the code and then post that code here. Good luck. (You may want to rethink the location you're toggling the value of `firstturn`, which may help.)

Comment: You could try moving the `first_turn = !first_turn;` to after the `if (!first_turn) { PuhTakTehMind(); }`.

Comment: @KeyurPATEL it makes the Letter 'O' to make every move.. still does not solve problem. but tnx for trying to help :)

Comment: This doesn't really solve your problem, but it may help in the future: I very strongly recommend naming variables after what they actually represent...  To me, a boolean called "first_turn" implies to me that it's only true on the first turn, then false every turn after that, and has nothing to do with which letter they are assigned. I'd instead call it something like "playerWentFirst" or something like that.  Also, your logic doesn't account for the player putting their X in the center square on the first move...

Answer (score 0):

If the letter O is selected, then `first_turn` starts out as false.
On the first button click, the button is set to the letter O and disabled.
Then `first_turn` is set to true on this line:
  `first_turn = !first_turn;`

Because of this, the AI routine is then skipped. It is the player turn again, but this time `first_turn` is true, so the player will set an X on the board.

That's what the program is actually written to do. It's your work as part of the assignment to write a program that fits the requirements, and there are infinitely many ways to do it.